# prime numbers in r counting and printing at the same time

Tags: r, function

```
prime <- function(x){
}
```

could you use the function above to print out numbers between 1 and 100 AND count the prime numbers less than 100. Only use the function above.

Here's the part of what I attempted below:

```
for (x in 1:20) {
if(is.prime(x))
print(x)
}
```

I'm not sure how to combine that with a statement saying there are 25 prime numbers between 0 and 100

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing the `is.prime` function. Presumably it is something like this:

```
is.prime <- function(p) {
  if(p == 1) return(FALSE)
  else return(!any(p %% seq(1, floor(p - 1))[-1] == 0))
}
```

Anyway, as well as printing the primes with your loop, you can increment a `counter` variable every time your loop comes across a prime number.

```r
counter <- 0

for(i in 1:100) {
  if(is.prime(i)) {
    print(i)
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 5
#> [1] 7
#> [1] 11
#> [1] 13
#> [1] 17
#> [1] 19
#> [1] 23
#> [1] 29
#> [1] 31
#> [1] 37
#> [1] 41
#> [1] 43
#> [1] 47
#> [1] 53
#> [1] 59
#> [1] 61
#> [1] 67
#> [1] 71
#> [1] 73
#> [1] 79
#> [1] 83
#> [1] 89
#> [1] 97
```

And the number of primes will be stored in `counter`:

```
counter
#> [1] 25
```